# Infinite shots fired in a lattice forest

Tags: number-theory, cardinals, lebesgue-integral, infinity

A [hunter is standing in the center of an infinite 2D forest](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7634/you-are-standing-at-the-origin-of-an-infinite-forest-holding-an-infinite-bb-g). There are point trees at all the integer lattice points. The hunter fires a gun with a bullet of zero width in a random direction. He misses ([with probability one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_surely)) of course, because the set of angles in which *can* hit the tree have measure zero, i.e. while there are an infinite number of trees, they are *countably infinite*.

What happens when the hunter takes many shots, whose angles make up the set $A$ when

1. $|A|=c$, where c is finite
2. $|A|=|\mathbb{Q}|$, a countably infinite number of shots
3. $|A|=|\mathbb{R}|$, a uncountably infinite number of shots

When the hunter takes a finite number of shots as in `1.` he still misses each shot with probability one. What about `2.` and `3.`? My intuition says that he still misses with probability one for all but the last one, as you can map each shot from `2.` onto the rational points over $\mathbb{Q}^2$, but I'm not sure how to prove this.

**Edit**: At Qiaochu's suggestion, the text of question has been changed from always misses to misses with probability one.

Comment: There is only one man who can fire infinitely many shots. But he doesn't have to shoot. He can roundhouse kick everything.

Comment: @AsafKaragila you da real mvp

Answer (score 2):

If the hunter fires a gun once in a direction uniformly chosen at random with respect to the unique translation-invariant probability measure on angles, he misses with probability $1$. This is *not* the same as saying that he always misses; there's a *non-empty* measure-zero event corresponding to him hitting something. In probability theory the usual way to say this is that he misses [almost surely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_surely), to emphasize that he doesn't miss *surely*. See also [this math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155156/is-it-generally-accepted-that-if-you-throw-a-dart-at-a-number-line-you-will-neve).

This remains true for a finite number of shots, but after that there are issues with defining infinite [product measures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_measure) that I'm not familiar with. I think things are okay for countable products of probability spaces but I don't know what happens after that.

Comment: Thanks for the correction in terminology, I need to get in the habit being more precise - I do understand the difference between _always misses_ and _misses almost surely_. I'm going to edit in the difference into the question to be more clear. To summarize the 2nd paragraph of your answer, you say `1.` almost surely misses, `2.` (you think) almost surely misses `3.` (you have no idea). Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. I'm uncomfortable about the third case.

Answer (score 0):

Restrict the shooting spree to the first quadrant. Then the tree at $(x, y)$ is at an angle with a *rational* tangent $y / x$. Just make the hunter shoot only at angles with *irrational* tangents, those are equinumerous to $\mathbb{R}$ and miss every time.

Comment: I don’t think that this answers the question. I take the question to be: if the hunter fires $2^\omega$ independent shots, each in a direction chosen at random w.r.t. the uniform distribution on $[0,2\pi)$, does he miss with probability $1$? We know that he *can* miss.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott is correct in the interpretation. The uniform distribution was implied by the fact that the hunter doesn't aim but "fires randomly".

Comment: @Hooked, "randomly" is not "uniformly"... it just implies _some_ distribution.

Comment: @vonbrand I know, I know! Like the exchange with Qiaochu, what I _imply_ and what I say are not always the same thing. I appreciate the corrections to help get at what I'm asking. Nonetheless, Brian does indeed state the question more formally.