# When - during the study and development of- - and how were complex numbers introduced in the study of [real-valued] power series (expansions)?

Tags: complex-numbers, math-history, power-series

Follow-up to: [Mathematical reason for the validity of the equation: $S=1+x^2S$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70048/mathematical-reason-for-the-validity-of-the-equation-s-1-x2-s) and [General question on relation between infinite series and complex numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68746/general-question-on-relation-between-infinite-series-and-complex-numbers)

(This question seems broad at this stage, but I will (re-)edit as answers and responses come by.)

---

It is said that complex numbers play a central role in the study of power series.

My question: When - during the study and development of- - and how were complex numbers introduced in the study of [real-valued] power series (expansions)? Specifically, what was the first motivation to introduce complex numbers to study power series (expansions)?

Comment: I don't know much about the historical development, but one clearly central role is that the radius of convergence of a power series is determined by all singularities in the _complex_ plane -- and the radius of convergence again determines which _real_ interval the series converges for (modulo inclusion/exclusion of the endpoints).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a nice brief history of complex numbers at [University of Alberta MATH department](http://www.ualberta.ca/MATH/gauss/fcm/Complex/Numbers/CmplxNmbrs_hstr.htm).  I also found a very nice [historical resource compiled here](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/do_you_know/fundamental.shtml), and of course [Mathematics and Its History](http://books.google.com/books?id=V7mxZqjs5yUC&pg=PA315#v=onepage&q&f=false) by John Stillwell is a very good source.

From what I have been able to gather by doing some basic perusal is that while imaginary numbers are attributed to [Cardano](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerolamo_Cardano), [Bombelli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rafael_Bombelli) did formal systematic analysis in 1572.

It is my personal inference from cursory reading that $${1 \over (1-x)} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n \quad \forall \|x\| \lt 1$$ combined with Bernoulli's observation (circ. 1702) that 
$${1 \over {1 + x^2}} = {1 \over 2} \left({1 \over {1 - ix}} + { 1 \over { 1 + ix }}\right)$$ and that $$\int \! {1 \over {1+ax}} \mathrm{d}x = {1 \over a} ln(1+ax) + C,$$

we get an inkling of the timeline when a relationship between the two can be seen in Western mathematics. Euler knew about these relationships as well. [Wikipedia article has better explanation and references regarding this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula#History).

Let me know if you find something profound in there somewhere.