# How did B. Riemann find the first three non-trivial zeros of the zeta function, how did he calculate that $s = 1/2 + it$?

Tags: reference-request, riemann-zeta

I followed this question, and it is simply the curiosity that drives me to learn the process of counting...
However, all I found was that it was calculated using the Riemann-Siegel formula, and I could not find the original study...
Could someone help me with this, which I would like to thank with deep gratitude! :D

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7783/proving-a-known-zero-of-the-riemann-zeta-has-real-part-exactly-1-2), which discusses the Riemann-Siegel formula, but also other methods. I suppose you have Riemann's (short) paper? What is he writing?

Comment: The Book "Riemann's Zeta Function" by H. M. Edwards gives a really good account of the methods and tools used by Riemann to investigate the Zeta function.