# Does this limit exist?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Does this limit exist?

$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sum_{(i=1)}^n (-1)^{i-1} \frac{1}{i} $$

Also, is there a name for this sum?

Comment: Yes, by the alternating series test. Are you familiar with the Taylor series of the natural logarithm?

Comment: It's sometimes referred to as the "alternating harmonic series".

Comment: I think it equals to $\log 2$

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This series is sometimes referred to as the *alternating harmonic series*. (An alternating series is just a series with alternating nonnegative and nonpositive terms.)

The convergence of this series follows directly from the *alternating series test* or the *Leibniz test*, of which this series gives an ideal textbook example.

> **Alternating series test.** Suppose that the sequence $\lbrace a_n \rbrace_{n \geq 1}$ is monotonically decreasing and converges to $0$. Then the alternating series $\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1} a_n$ converges.

On the other hand, it is **not** absolutely convergent, since the harmonic series $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ famously [diverges again and again](http://prairiestate.edu/skifowit/harmapa.pdf). (See also this question: [255](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/255/why-does-the-series-1-1-1-2-1-3-not-converge).)

It turns out that we also know the exact sum of the series. The logarithmic function has the Taylor expansion: 
$$
\ln (1+x) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1} \frac{x^n}{n} \ \ \ \  (-1 \lt x \lt 1),
$$
with a radius of convergence $1$. Since $1$ is the end-point of the interval of convergence, it is not immediately clear that one can plug in $1$ in the above series. However, [Abel's theorem for power series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel's_theorem), in fact, guarantees that 
$$
\lim_{x \to 1-} \ln(1+x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}.
$$ 
Thus the series evaluates to $\ln 2 \approx 0.693\ldots$.

*This answer is mostly an elaboration of Qiaochu Yuan and J.M.'s comments. Thanks to Robert Israel for pointing out the need for Abel's theorem.*

Comment: Since $1$ is an endpoint of the interval of convergence, it's not so obvious that the sum of your series is $\ln 2$.  You need Abel's theorem.  See e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem

Comment: @Robert You are correct. But I was not trying to derive the domain of convergence. I was more like, well, stating it from the know-it-all wikipedia. :-) I will update my answer to be more complete.