# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2\cdot n}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

It is possible to deduce the value of the following (in my opinion) converging infinite series? If yes, then what is it?

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2\cdot n}$$

where **n** is an integer. Sorry if the notation is a bit off, I hope youse get the idea.

Comment: The series diverges: it’s simply $1/2$ of the [harmonic series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_%28mathematics%29), which is a standard example of a divergent series.

Comment: The series diverges! Do you know that [Harmonic Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)) Diverges? Then use that fact (it requires proof!) to conclude that this series diverges!

Comment: You'll have a hard time with that one. If you factor out the half, then you are left with the harmonic series.

Comment: Opinions aren't worth much in mathematics - do you have any *reason* for thinking that series converges?

Comment: @GerryMyerson - As you might have guessed, I am not a mathematician and unfortunately I don't have the time to become one. That is why I asked.

Comment: @Curious Are you willing to know the proof of divergence ofHarmonic series! If you already know, I suggest that you upvote and accept Americo Tavares' Answer as it addresses your problem. The question will stand solved for all purposes in the site!

Comment: OK, but usually when people have opinions, those opinions are based on something. I'm "curious" as to the basis for your opinion that the series converges.

Comment: @KannappanSampath - Yes I am willing to accept the official position of Your church. So be it, bless You with Euler, Fermat and other saints.

Comment: @GerryMyerson - and surely the basis of an opinion must be based on something else etc etc. But seriously.. I got a decent answer and see no benefit in arguing over supposed merits or shortcomings of reasoning that lead to this question. Thanks again, and take care.

Comment: See also this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/255/why-does-the-series-frac-1-1-frac-12-frac-13-cdots-not-converge

Comment: I'm glad you got a helpful answer. The benefit in discussing the reasoning that led to a question is that you might learn something about how to decide mathematical questions that interest you, or how to phrase such questions when asking them of other people. I don't see the benefit in shutting down discussion of unresolved points.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The series is not convergent, since it is half of the [harmonic series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_%28mathematics%29) which is known to be divergent$^1$.

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{2n}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{n}.$$

--

$^1$ The sum of the following $k$ terms is greater or equal to $\frac{1}{2}$

$$\frac{1}{k+1}+\frac{1}{k+2}+\ldots +\frac{1}{2k-1}+\frac{1}{2k}\geq
k\times \frac{1}{2k}=\frac{1}{2},$$

because each term is greater or equal to $\frac{1}{2k}$.

Comment: I'd upvote this if I could but I don't have the necessary reputation just yet.

Comment: @Curious: Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To me, the easiest way to see that the harmonic series diverges is to use the Integral test. Then you do not have to deal with coming up with a formula.