# Is the infinite sum of $2 ^{-n}$ convergent? Why?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

As a follow-up to a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101618/convergence-of-infinite-series), I'd like to know if

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2 ^ n}$$

is convergent? If yes, then what does it converge to?

Just as a sidenote - the whole issue started with reading about Zeno's Turtle Paradox which made me curious about the underlying mathematics.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series

Comment: Sure, the terms go to $0$ real fast.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This series is a geometric series and converges, see the link in the comments.

But, I'll offer the standard proof that this particular series converges  here:

A series is defined to converge to $L$ if and only if the sequence of its partial sums converges to $L$:

> The infinite series $ \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges to $L$ if and only if the
>   sequence of partial sums $\{S_n\}$, defined by
>   $$S_n=\sum\limits_{m=1}^n a_m =a_1+a_2+a_3+\cdots+a_n,$$ converges to
>   $L$.

If you consider the sum of the first $n$ terms, $S_n$, for $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty {1\over 2^n}$, then
$$S_n=\sum\limits_{m=1}^n{1\over2^m}.$$ Writing out this sum explicitly gives
$$
S_n={1\over 2}+{1\over 2^2}+\cdots+{1\over 2^n}.
$$
Multiply both sides of the above by $1\over2$:
$$
{1\over 2} S_n = {1\over 2^2}+{1\over 2^3}+\cdots+{1\over 2^{n+1}}
$$
Now add $1\over2$ to both sides:
$$
{1\over 2} S_n+{1\over2} =\underbrace{{1\over 2}+ {1\over 2^2}+{1\over 2^3}+\cdots+
+{1\over 2^n}}_{S_n}+{1\over 2^{n+1}}
$$
Then:
$$
{1\over 2} S_n+{1\over2} =S_n+{1\over 2^{n+1}}.
$$
Solving the above  for $S_n$ gives:
$$
{1\over2}-{1\over 2^{n+1}}={1\over2}S_n
$$
$$
S_n=1-{1\over 2^n}.
$$
From  the above, we can see that
as $n\rightarrow\infty$, $S_n\rightarrow1$. So $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty {1\over 2^n}=1$.

---

Or, consider the partition of the unit square:

[image]

Comment: +1, very nice wordless proof at the bottom! More nice proofs at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/8846/proofs-without-words