# How to find a limit to $\sum_{r=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{r-1}}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request

I know that the limit is one, but what are the steps to take in order to find a limit? Maybe there are sources online where it is explained in detail?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is the infinite sum of $2 ^{-n}$ convergent? Why?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101624/is-the-infinite-sum-of-2-n-convergent-why) (note that your sum is the same sum as the one in the linked question)

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

As a geometric series,

$$S=\frac 12+\frac 14+\frac 18+....$$
$$=\frac 12(1+S)$$

$$\implies 2S=1+S$$