# Why do we say the harmonic series is divergent?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, infinity

If we have $\Sigma\frac{1}{n}$, why do we say it is divergent? Yes, it is constantly increasing, but after a certain point, $n$ will be so large that we will be certain of millions of digits. If we continue to let $n$ increase, we will end up with a number so large in the denominator that there will be an infinite amount of digits locked into place. What we would have left would just be an irrational number, correct? $\pi$ is an irrational number, but we still consider the value of that to be know. The common estimation of $\pi$ is 3.141592, and we can calculate it past 1,000,000 decimal places, so why can we just assume that we know the first few million places of the harmonic series, slap an irrational label on it, and call it a day? After all, the series $\Sigma\frac{1}{n^n}$ is convergent, and it basically does the same thing, it just gets there a lot faster.

I feel like argument has probably been made before, so I feel like there's probably a proof somewhere proving me wrong, if someone could point me to that.

Comment: Do you know what the word "divergent" means here?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/q/255/ for proofs that its partial sums increase *without an upper bound* (unlike $\sum\frac{1}{n^n}$), hence it [diverges](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_series).

Comment: "Yes, it is constantly increasing, but after a certain point, n will be so large that we will be certain of millions of digits" is not true, because all the digits change frequently. The thing is that while $\frac{1}{n}$ is smaller and smaller, few of them add to something big. For example $\frac{1}{n}+...+\frac{1}{2n} > \frac{1}{2}$... So if you "know" the first 1 billion digits at step $n$, double the step and te first billion digits are NOT the same....

Comment: Ah thanks for the proof link. That actually makes a lot of sense. It just always seemed to me that it would result in an irrational number. See, this is why I'm in school to be an engineer, not a mathematician. I'll just accept that that is divergent, apply it, and call it a day. WHY it works is waaaay over my head.

Comment: Also, whole lot of how-could-you-be-so-wrong agression on this question, guys. I even stated that I knew I was wrong about the assumptions I made, I just wanted to understand *why* I was wrong about them. This has cleared things up a lot.

Comment: Nick: Which answer(s) do you see, in full or partly, as *how-could-you-be-so-wrong agression* (s)? (This is a serious question.)

Comment: Mainly, the first comment. This question wasn't "I think math should work this way, why doesn't it?" like so many other questions, this was an "Explain to me why I'm wrong because I suck at math" kind question.

Comment: Your question seemed to conflate the terms irrational and divergent, so that person and  others (including me) were sort of confused.

Comment: -1 because a proof of this fact can be found in any calculus textbook...and you could then ask 'I don't understand this or this part of the proof'.

Comment: I just realized why I was misunderstanding this! I was thinking of $lim\frac{1}{n}$ which is zero, but that's because the *value* gets closer to zero. But in a sum, the value may be getting closer to zero, but the running total still continues to get bigger.

Comment: Unfortunately, this test book does not have a proof of it. In fact, this textbook is awful. I find myself googling for answer to questions every couple of minutes because it completely and total fails to explain *why* I'm doing something, it only explains *how*, which helps very little.

Comment: Nick: If you are referring to the comment *Do you know what the word "divergent" means here?* by @David Spencer, let me mention that I am 110% sure this comment has 0% *aggression* in it. This is a standard question, asked to determine the approximate level of mathematical sophistication of the OP, so that the level of an answer is appropriate. No spite here, you can relax...

Comment: @Nick And please use the symbol @, like at the beginning of the present comment, to signal your own comment.

Comment: I certainly intended no offense, and I regret that my wording offended you. As @did says, I was simply checking your understanding, as your second sentence seems to imply (to me) that any constantly increasing series is divergent regardless of whether it tends to infinity at the limit. We can answer most usefully and clearly if we know whether to focus on the terminology or the proof. I hope there are no hard feelings.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The sum $\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}$ is $\gt \frac{1}{2}$.

The sum  $\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{8}$ is $\gt \frac{1}{2}$. This is easy, we have $4$ terms, each $\ge \frac{1}{8}$, and all but one $\gt \frac{1}{8}$.

The sum $\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{10}+\cdots+\frac{1}{16}$ is $\gt 
\frac{1}{2}$. We have $8$ terms, each $\ge \frac{1}{16}$, and all but one $\gt \frac{1}{16}$.

The sum $\frac{1}{17}+\frac{1}{18}+\cdots +\frac{1}{32}$ is $\gt \frac{1}{2}$.

The sum of the terms $\frac{1}{33}$ to $\frac{1}{64}$ is $\gt \frac{1}{2}$.

The sum of the terms $\frac{1}{65}$ to $\frac{1}{128}$ is $\gt \frac{1}{2}$.

And so on.

Counting in the first two terms, if we add until the term $\frac{1}{4}$ our sum is $\gt 2$. If we add up to $\frac{1}{8}$, our sum is $\gt 2.5$. Adding to $\frac{1}{16}$ puts us beyond $3$. At $32$ terms, we are beyond $3.5$. At $64$ terms, we are beyond $4$. At $256$, we are beyond $5$. At $1024$, we are beyond $6$. At $4096$, we are beyond $7$.

Painfully slow! But if we are patient enough, after a while (a long long while) we will be beyond $10$, beyond $100$, beyond $1000$. But the universe may end first.

**Remarks:** On a *calculator*, the sum is finite! Because of roundoff, after a while we are just adding $0$.

The answer dealt with the series $\sum \frac{1}{n}$. It turns out that for any *positive* $\epsilon$, the series  $\sum \frac{1}{n^{1+\epsilon}}$ converges. We can take for example $\epsilon=0.0001$. So one can say that $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ diverges extremely reluctantly, and that close neighbours converge.

Comment: Yes! That end part is a perfect explanation. That sums up what I was thinking, the harmonic series really, really, *really* wants to converge (if we're anthropomorphizing numbers now), but it can't quite get there. It just needs a little push of $\epsilon = 0.0000000…000000001$ to get there. I get it now.

Comment: @NickAnderegg What do you mean by "$000\dots00001$"?

Comment: @PeterTamaroff: I think that he means that even though $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ diverges, a any tiny change in the exponent, from $1$ to $1+\epsilon$, where say $\epsilon=0.000\dots 00001$, where the $\dots$ stands for an unspecified but fixed number of $0$'s, pushes the series into convegence territory, which indeed it does.

Answer (score 11):

What you are trying to argue is that if $a_n$ is a sequence of non-negative numbers, and $a_n\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ then the sum $\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_n$ ought to converge.

Unfortunately, that is not true. It would simplify a lot of math if it was true.

Have you seen the proof that it diverges?

Let $$s_m=\sum_{n=1}^m \frac 1 n$$

be the $m$th partial sum.

Then $$s_{2m}-s_{m} = \sum_{n=m+1}^{2m} \frac{1}{n} \geq \sum_{n=m+1}^{2m}\frac{1}{2m} = \frac{1}{2}.$$

In particular, you can show by induction that $s_{2^k} \geq \frac{k}{2}$.  So $s_m$ can be made as large as you like.

Answer (score 9):

The idea with the harmonic series is that you can let
$$
\sum_{n=1}^N \frac 1n
$$
to be *as large as you want*. It's not because we "cannot compute it precisely enough" that we label it infinity ; it because *it doesn't make sense to attribute a real number to its value in the sense of*
$$
\lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^N \frac 1n.
$$
If you have ever seen the proof of the divergence of this sum, here it is :
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{2^N} \frac 1n = 1 + \sum_{i=1}^{N} \sum_{n=2^{i-1}+1}^{2^i} \frac 1n \ge \sum_{i=1}^{N} \sum_{n=2^{i-1}+1}^{2^i}\frac 1{2^i} = \sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac 12 = \frac N2
$$
and letting $N \to \infty$ means that in particular the sum
$$
\sum_{n=1}^K \frac 1n \ge \sum_{n=1}^{2^N} \frac 1n \ge \frac N2
$$
if we take $K$ such that $K > 2^N$. If you don't understand the formalism, the idea is that I just regrouped the terms like this :
$$
1 + \frac 12 + \frac 13 + \frac 14 + \frac 15 + \frac 16 + \frac 17 + \frac 18 + \dots \ge 1 + \frac 12 + (\frac 14 + \frac 14) + (\frac 18 + \frac 18 + \frac 18 + \frac 18) + \dots
$$
and that by using $2^i$ terms each time, I can bound by below each term of, say $\frac 1{17},\frac 1{18}, \dots, \frac 1{32}$ by $\frac 1{32}$, and since there are $16$ such terms, the sum of them is $\frac 12$. And it keeps going on like this.

Hope that helps,

Comment: I think $\sum_{i = 1}^N \frac 1 2$ is equal to $\frac N 2$, not $\frac {N - 1} 2$, although this isn't a big deal.

Comment: @jskattt797 thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 4):

Consider the sum 
$$H_n = \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}$$
for $n=1,2,\ldots$. 
These are called the [harmonic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).
You are interested in $\lim_{n\to\infty}H_n$.

Notice that $H_3 = 1 +\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}$ is just the area of the shaded region between $x=1$ and $x=4$ in the figure below.
For any $n$ the area of the shaded region will be larger than the corresponding area under the red line, the graph of $y = \frac{1}{x}$.
This implies
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
H_n &=& \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} \\
&>& \int_1^{n+1} \frac{dx}{x} \\
&>& \int_1^n \frac{dx}{x}.
\end{eqnarray*}$$
Similarly, an upper bound can be found, 
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
H_n &<& 1+\int_{2}^{n+1} \frac{dx}{x-1} \\
&=& 1+ \int_1^n \frac{dx}{x}.
\end{eqnarray*}$$
Therefore, 
$$\log n < H_n < \log n + 1.$$
The lower bound implies $\lim_{n\to\infty}H_n = \infty$, that is, the sum grows without bound. 
In addition we find $H_n \sim \log n \, (n\to\infty)$, that is, $H_n$ behaves like $\log n$ for large $n$.

Your intuition that $H_n$ grows very slowly is spot on. 
Roughly, if we want the sum to be some number $N$ we need about 
$e^N$ terms. 
For example, $H_n \simeq 185{}^\dagger$ for $n \simeq e^{185}$.
*That is, we need as many terms as there are atoms in the universe for the sum to reach $185$.*

[image: Illustration of the integral test in calculus. Integral_Test.svg, By Jim Belk (User:Jim.belk) (Own work) [Public domain], via Wikimedia Commons]

Figure 1. *Illustration of the integral test in calculus* by Jim Belk.

---

<sub>${}^\dagger$ Actually, $H_n \simeq 185.577$.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

No digits will be locked. It's diverging because given any number X, if you add together enough terms of the sum you will eventually exceed X. (Using finite number of terms.)

Answer (score 0):

The number in the denominator would be large, but the numerator would be larger. "Infinitely larger", which is the whole point.

$$...123129.120931293...$$

(random example) is *not* an irrational number because of the infinitely many digits *to the left*. You can write the digits down (sort of), but they don't have a number associated with them this way. A real number is in fact often defined as the limit of a converging sequence, so a sequence that gets larger and larger can't be a real number by definition. Trying to assign a real number to $\sum_1^\infty\frac 1 n$ is like trying to give me the largest integer. Whatever answer you give, I can go higher, so the answer doesn't exist.

Comment: The example is meant to show that even if digits were eventually fixed, that still doesn't imply that it has a limit.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake you make here is the standard mistake many students make when they think convergence of $\sum a_n$ is the same as $\lim a_n =0$.

The so called Divergence test sais that if the first happens then the second must hold, but the converse is not true. And here is the reason why:

If $\lim a_n =0$, then $a_n$ becomes smaller and smaller, but when you calculate $\sum a_n$ you add MANY terms, and the sum of many small numbers can be anything. It is very similar to the type of limit $\infty \cdot 0$, you have infinitely many terms, all of them close to 0....
And anything can happen in this case.

For this series, what happens is that more and more terms will agree on the first "few" digits, but then KABOOM you get a term with new digits..The actual series, or more correctly, the sequence of partial sums $s_n$, goes to infinity very very slowly, but it grows to infinity...

$s_n$ actually behaves exactly like $\ln(n)$, and looking to this sequence migth clarify a little what happens: $\ln(n) \to \infty$ but $\frac{1}{n} \sim \ln(n+1)-\ln(n) \to 0$. 
Exactly like $\ln(n)$, $s_n$ grows to $\infty$, even if at each step it grows by $s_n-s_{n-1}$, an amount which goes to 0....