# Is there an intuitive non-mathematical way to show $\sum_n 1/n=\infty$?

Tags: soft-question

I want to show some school students about the sum of the harmonic series diverging and I need some nice interpretation for this. I'll preferably love to have a figure.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Isn't the standard proof enough (grouping elements that add up to 1 or more)? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172504/why-do-we-say-the-harmonic-series-is-divergent

Comment: @Lepidopterist: I do not seem a proof exactly, but more of a figure where you can see the obvious!

Comment: Guru, then make a really good diagram up to $n=8$

Comment: http://prairiestate.edu/skifowit/harmapa.pdf

Comment: I doubt you'll find a "non-mathematical" way, given that this is, after all, maths.

Comment: Following @Lepidopterist, [here are 22 more proofs](http://prairiestate.edu/skifowit/harm2.pdf).

Comment: Look at the (first) book *Proofs without words*.

Comment: I'll need to elaborate on one of the "visual proofs" in the second pdf, I think. I was looking for one of those in the answer section actually.

Comment: How much math have these students previously had?

Answer (score 12):

One way is to bound the series below by a series that more immediately looks infinite. We round down $1/n$ to largest fraction of the form $1/2^k,k\in\mathbb N$. This is illustrated as such:
\begin{align*}
&1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{8}\ldots\\
\geq&1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}\ldots
\end{align*}
Hopefully that presentation is clear enough. We may combine terms in this lower sum to see (loosely) that we are adding up $1/2$ an infinite number of times.  This shows that the sum diverges, at least sufficiently for illustrative purposes.