# What is the sum of series 1/2+1/4+1/6+… up to infinity?

Tags: sequences-and-series

So someone told me its infinity, but i don't get it

it sure looks like its just keep getting smaller and smaller so how is this going to infinity? or is it?

I know that 1+1/2+1/4+1/8+... is 1 so how is this infinity?

Comment: The harmonic series is divergent: $a_n\to 0$ is not enough to ensure $\sum a_n<\infty$.

Comment: The sum $1+1/2+1/4+1/8+\ldots$ is $2$, not $1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{4}+\dfrac{1}{6}+\dfrac{1}{8}+\cdots=\dfrac{1}{2}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{3}+\dfrac{1}{4}+\cdots\right)
$$

Comment: Wow that's actually a very simple and great answer, i googled and the previous answers on stackexchange were so vague. Thank you. also for those who might not know, the sum of 1+1/2+1/3+... is infinite so this is why.

Answer (score 1):

No, sorry. Note that the sum: $$S = 1 +\frac12 +\frac14 + \frac18 +\ldots$$ converges to $\color{red} 2$. A typo perhaps?

Now, the sum: $$S = \frac12 + \frac14+\frac16+\ldots$$ $$= \frac12 \left[1 + \frac12 + \frac13 + \ldots \right] $$ $$= \frac12 S_1$$ where $S_1$ diverges as [was shown here on MSE earlier](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172504/why-do-we-say-the-harmonic-series-is-divergent).