# My (simpler) proof of the divergence of a harmonic series.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $H=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots$ . Proving that it diverges this is what I did.

I supposed that the series converges to $H$,  :

$$H\geq1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}+\dots=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\cdots$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}+H$$

And we have reached a contradiction with the series converging to $H$ hence concluding the proof. Do I have any mistakes?

Comment: How do you **exactly** form the series to the right of the first $\;\ge\;$ and how then you prove the inequality?

Comment: I saw essentially this proof in a brief note in the _Monthly_ in the late '90s.

Comment: @DonAntonio: it seems perfectly clear to me. There is no rearrangment of terms, just term-by-term comparison.

Comment: I'm happy it does to you, @TonyK . It didn't to me and that's why I asked...

Comment: The series to the right of the inequality holds because $\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}>\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}$ and $\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}>\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{6}$

Comment: This is the exact same proof a lecturer gave us back in calculus 1 some 28 years ago, after seeing other more usual proofs. It's nice and correct, imo.

Comment: @TonyK Yes i had edited it before, but thank you very much.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does the series $\frac 1 1 + \frac 12 + \frac 13 + \cdots$ not converge?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/255/why-does-the-series-frac-1-1-frac-12-frac-13-cdots-not-converge)

Comment: @ALGEAN I have never even seen that post.