# Need counter examples for statements related to sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

Which of the following doesnot ensure the convergence of real sequence ${a_n}$

A.  |$a_n - a_{n+1}|$ goes to zero as n goes to infinity

B .$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty$ |$a_n - a_{n+1}|$ is convergent

C. $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty$ $na_n$  is convergent

Comment: @user184794 sorry it was a typo .i have edited the q

Comment: Please add your thoughts on the problem for better answers

Comment: @learnmore I was taking a convergent sequence (also took harmonic numbers ) and was checking with conditions so that after  doing calculations it becomes divergent , which ain't happened . But here answer is just the reverse of what i was doing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to show that a condition does not ensure the convergence of a sequence, we must show there exists a sequence which fulfills the condition, but is not convergent.

The sequence of [harmonic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) satisfies condition A:

$$H_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac 1 k\\
\left|H_n-H_{n+1}\right| = \left|-\frac 1 {n+1}\right| = \frac 1 {n+1}\to0$$

But it is not convergent (shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/259/184794) or on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_%28mathematics%29#Divergence)).

So condition A does not ensure convergence.