# Is a positive series convergent if the terms decrease?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

Suppose  positive real numbers $n_1>n_2>n_3>n_4...$ with these properties are given and you have the sum of  $ n_1+n_2+n_3+n_4...$
Is it possible to determine on the basis of this information whether or not the series will converge?

Comment: No : $\sum\frac{1}{n}$ won't converge whereas $\sum\frac{1}{n^2}$ will.

Comment: If it won't converge will it then necessarily diverge to infinity?

Comment: Yes because you are adding positive terms : the case where the limit doesn't exists is excluded.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I don't see how adding positive terms will necessarily lead to infinity: since $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$ is also positive but does not lead to infinity.

Comment: I didn't say that ; I just said there is two possibilities, convergence to a positive term or divergence (the case $\sum(-1)^n$ where the limit doesn't exists can't be encounter if you considerate positive numbers).

Comment: I guess I need some help understanding that. if I understood correctly $\sum \frac {1} {n}$ will diverge, and will go toward infinity. The part which I don't understand is why does it go toward infinity? (And will not stay under an arbitrary number like 1 million or so).

Comment: You can show that the partial sum $\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k}$ is equivalent to $\ln(n)$. Then it will grow slowly, but surely to $+\infty$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30602/discussion-between-st-clair-bij-and-baloown).

Comment: @St.ClairBij There have been multiple questions on why the harmonic series diverges. See for example [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/255/why-does-the-series-sum-n-1-infty-frac1n-not-converge?lq=1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No, the series might converge or diverge.** The two classic examples are the harmonic series, $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty {\frac{1}{n}}$, which diverges, and the series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty {\frac{1}{n^2}}$, which converges to $\pi^2/6$.