# Discrete Mathematics Proving Question

Tags: induction

I need help with this proof. I am stuck on this question and don't know how to do it:

Prove that:

$$ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \sum\limits_{i=2}^{2^n} \frac{1}{i} \geq \frac{n}{2}$$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n$ not converge?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/255/why-does-the-series-sum-n-1-infty-frac1n-not-converge)

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Show that the following is true:

$$\underbrace{\frac12}_{\geq \frac12} + \underbrace{\frac13+\frac14}_{\geq \frac12} + \underbrace{\frac15+\frac16+\frac17+\frac18}_{\geq \frac12}+\ldots + \underbrace{\frac1{2^{n-1}+1}+\ldots+\frac1{2^n}}_{\geq \frac12}$$

Comment: Great explanation, great visual!

Comment: I may sound stupid, but what significance does that have?

Comment: @Johnny — There are $n$ bracketed groups, and each of them contributes (at least) $\frac12$ to the sum. That makes for a total of $\frac n2$, which is the right-hand side in your inequality.