# How can $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$ be simplified

Tags: sequences-and-series, harmonic-numbers

So I'm doing year 9/10 now and I've just been working with sigmas $\Sigma$.

I found across a question which I found quite tricky.

Is there a way to write down the answer to this question or make it easier:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$$

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: The series is called the [Harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)).  It is notable for being divergent.

Comment: there are many articles about the harmonic series in the internet

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you're asking

Comment: I disagree to downvote a high school student.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, I suspect he assumes there is some sort of closed form for this expression, like for many other series, for example sum of the first n integers. Closed form here, a formular can just type in a calculator in less than 10 seconds to solve a problem, which would take ten times longer normally.

Comment: It can be simplified as $\infty$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust One should always be reluctant to just simplify a sum to infinity. For example, $\frac{\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 2 n}{\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1 n} \rightarrow \frac \infty \infty \rightarrow ?$.

Comment: See [Why does the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n$ not converge?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/255/why-does-the-series-sum-n-1-infty-frac1n-not-converge) (and perhaps also other questions [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/255).)

Comment: @PichiWuana [The first edit](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1938736/revisions) after the question is put on hold puts question into reopen review queue. (For more details see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16820/should-i-avoid-minor-edit-of-a-question-which-was-put-on-hold/16821#16821).) In this case, the result [was to leave it closed](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/686443). It is advisable that the first edit after putting on hold is substantial enough that it addresses the issues why the post has been put on hold.

Comment: @Axoren: it is a well-known fact that $\frac\infty\infty=2$.

Comment: @MartinSleziak oh ok didn't know that

Comment: I don't see anything at all wrong with this question. The answer is fairly well known to people who have taken a few maths courses, but not to 10-th graders.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: You should not joke like this: less experienced people might take you seriously just because you have a high MSE reputation. Or at least use smileys.

Comment: @JeanMarie Any high school student? Whichever question they ask? This seems utterly unreasonable...

Comment: @AlexM. Especially since $\frac\infty\infty=42$.

Comment: I reopened, then voted to close as duplicate, just so we can get the close reason right on the cleaned-up question.

Comment: Since I can't add an answer here, I added one to the duplicate question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/255/why-does-the-series-sum-n-1-infty-frac1n-not-converge?noredirect=1&lq=1. It's very similar to some other answers, but with special emphasis on making it understandable to a 9th grade student.

Comment: @AlexM.: you are right, I forgot to smile.

Answer (score 16):

Consider breaking the sum, after the first term, into chunks with $2^{n-1}$ terms ending in $\frac1{2^n}$
$$
1+\overbrace{\ \ \ \ \ \frac12\ \ \ \ \ }^{\ge1/2}+\overbrace{\ \frac13+\frac14\ }^{\ge1/2}+\overbrace{\frac15+\frac16+\frac17+\frac18}^{\ge1/2}+\overbrace{\frac19+\frac1{10}+\cdots+\frac1{16}}^{\ge1/2}+
$$
You can see that we can add as many chunks as we wish that are at least as large as $\frac12$. By continuing in this fashion, the sum can be made as large as we want.

Comment: +1.  Good answer because it's expressed in an elementary jargon-free way  that many people (including the OP) will probably understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fact that the limiting difference between the natural logarithm and the Harmonic Series is the [Euler-Mascheroni Constant](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant) to estimate the $nth$ term of the series you are using. The only problem is that the Harmonic Series diverges, which you can prove using the integral test or various other tests.

Comment: The ratio test is inconclusive in proving divergence of the Harmonic series.  And "other tests" fail also.  There are several ways aside from the integral test, that do demonstrate divergence.

Comment: The [Cauchy Condensation Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) is a good test to show divergence here. It is equivalent to the demonstration in my answer.

Comment: @robjohn Thanks. I knew the proof with the powers of two, but I didn’t know that it was the Cauchy Condensation Test.