# How do I find n from the inequation?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have the inequation : $\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{n}>2012$ and I need to show that there is a n which satisfies it. How do I do it? I tried to show that it is bigger then $\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+...+\frac{1}{2^n}$ which is equal to $1-\frac{2^n-1}{2^{n-1}}$. Then I wanted to show that there is an n which makes that sum be bigger than 2012. Is it correct?
I found somewhere that it says : $1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{2^m}>1+\frac{m}{2}$ and then it says that $n=2^{4024}$. Why it is like that?

Comment: Starting somewhere would help.

Comment: Just show the sequence diverges.  That means there is an $n$, even if you can't point to one.

Comment: I do not even know how to start...

Comment: it might be help http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/255/why-does-the-series-sum-n-1-infty-frac1n-not-converge

Comment: No!  The method in your last edit is not correct.  You want to get that it is bigger than 1 + 1/2 + 1/2 + 1/2 + 1/2 + 1/2 + 1/2 ....

Comment: It is not correct cause it is useless or it is just not correct?

Comment: The useless part :) Because 1+1/2+1/4+1/8 ... = 2

Comment: I found somewhere that it says : $1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{2^m}>1+\frac{m}{2}$ and then it says that $n=2^{4024}$.

Comment: @OvyOvy Ah!  Just what I calculated as well ... see my updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just show the sequence diverges.  That means there is an $n$, even if you can't point to one.

It diverges because you can keep finding groups of terms that add up to 1/2 or more:

1 > 1/2

1/2 = 1/2

1/3+1/4 > 1/4 + 1/4 = 1/2

1/5+1/6+1/7+1/8 > 1/8+1/8+1/8+1/8 = 1/2

(then take the next 8 terms .. then the next 16 ... etc)

So the whole sum is greater than $ 1/2+1/2+1/2+1/2+ ... = \infty$

And with this method, you can point to an $n$ for which it is $> 2012$: we need 4024 of these groupings (since we need 4024*1/2=2012), and $m$ groupings take $2^{m-1}$ terms:

The first grouping (1) took 1 term,

the next (1/2) also 1 term,

the next (1/3+1/4) 2 terms,

the next 4 terms, etc., ...

so the first 3 groupings require 4 terms, for 4 groupings we need 8 terms, for 5 we need 16, and now you see the pattern: we need $2^{m-1}$ terms to get $m$ groupings of terms where each grouping sums up to 1/2 or more.

So for $n=2^{4023}$ we know it has surpassed 2012.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: The typical way to do that with this one is to point out that we can keep finding groups of terms that add up to 1/2 or more ... that is 1 > 1/2, 1/2 = 1/2, 1/3 + 1/4 > 1/2, 1/5+1/6+ ... > 1/2 (do you see how far you have to go? and how you can keep finding those groupings?)

Comment: @OvyOvy the most common "simple" proof is that $\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\dots+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{9}+\dots+\frac{1}{16}+\dots $  $> \frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+\dots+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{16}+\dots+\frac{1}{16}+\dots$  $=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+\dots$

Comment: Note that the approach will give an $n$ in the order of $2^{4000}$, while the true bound is between $2^{2901}$ and $2^{2902}$.

Comment: How do you find how many $\frac{1}{2}$ are depending on n?

Comment: @OvyOvy Just added some more explanation to my answer

Comment: I do not get it. I guess it's too hard for me. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Ok. After I read abit and wrote it down I managed to get it. Thank you.

Comment: @OvyOvy  Yay!  Glad I could help ... I am sure there are better explanations than mine ... but working it out yourself is always best!

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for $n$ such that $$S=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac 1i=H_n>2012$$ FOr sure, $n$ will be large; so, considering the asymptotics of the harmonic numbers $$H_n=\gamma +\log \left({n}\right)+\frac{1}{2
   n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ and ignoring higher order terms, you need to solve for $n$ $$\gamma +\log \left({n}\right)+\frac{1}{2
   n}=2012$$ the solution of which being given in terms of [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)  $$n=-\frac{1}{2 W\left(-\frac{1}{2} e^{\gamma -2012}\right)}$$ But, for small $x$, $W(x)\approx x$ which makes $$n\approx e^{2012-\gamma}\approx 355\times 10^{871}$$ and  for this value $S_n=2012.00095$.

Computing tables
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & H_n \\
 350 \times 10^{871} & 2011.98676 \\
 351 \times 10^{871} & 2011.98962 \\
 352 \times 10^{871} & 2011.99246 \\
 353 \times 10^{871} & 2011.99530 \\
 354  \times 10^{871}& 2011.99813 \\
 355 \times 10^{871} & 2012.00095 \\
 356 \times 10^{871} & 2012.00376 \\
 357 \times 10^{871} & 2012.00657 \\
 358 \times 10^{871} & 2012.00936 \\
 359 \times 10^{871} & 2012.01215 \\
 360 \times 10^{873} & 2012.01494
\end{array}
\right)$$