# The limit of $u_n=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{i}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, harmonic-numbers

I had this question : 
Does the sequence 
$$\begin{align*}
u_n=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{i}
\end{align*}$$
have a real end ? 
Well my teacher said no but the last question was

Is 
$$\begin{align*}
u_n=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{i^2}
\end{align*}$$
a convergent sequence ?

And we proved yes ...

I don't know maybe there is a problem in my understanding

Can a convergent sequence have no real limit ?
and if the first doesn't converge why doesn't it ? can it be proven in a similar way to the second?

Comment: See also: [Why does the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n$ not converge?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/255)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first get our definitions straight:

The following is a partial or finite sum:
$$s_n=\sum_{k=1}^na_k.$$

We call the infinite series (or infinite sum) $\sum_{k=1}^∞a_k$ convergent with limit $s_∞$, if its sequence of partial sums converges:
$$s_n=\sum_{k=1}^na_k → s_∞\qquad (n→∞).$$

The Cauchy-criterion for sequences states, that  an infinite sum is convergent if for all $ε>0$ there exists a $n_ε∈ℕ$, such that for all $n>m≥n_ε$ it holds:
$$|s_n-s_m|=\left|\sum_{k=m+1}^na_k\right|<ε.$$

---

The first infinite series you stated is
$$\sum_{k=1}^∞\frac{1}{k},$$
the so called harmonic series. 
For this series it holds
$$s_{2m}-s_m = \sum_{k=m+1}^{2m} \frac{1}{k} = \frac{1}{m+1} + …+\frac{1}{2m} > \underbrace{\frac{1}{2m}+…+\frac{1}{2m}}_{m \text{ times}} = \frac{1}{2}.$$ 
Hence the Cauchy criterion is not fulfilled and the series is **not** convergent.

---

The second infinite sum is $$\sum_{k=1}^∞\frac{1}{k^2}.$$
That sum is convergent, but we need the following lemma to help us proof that.

**Lemma:** Given two series $s_∞=\sum a_k$ and $s_∞'=\sum a_k'$, if for almost all $k∈ℕ$ it holds $$|a_k|≤κa_k',$$ 
with some constant $κ$, then the absolute convergence of $s_∞'$ ensures the convergence of $s_∞$.

Now we can use that. It is
$$\frac{1}{k^2} = \frac{1}{k(k+1)} + \frac{1}{k^2(k+1)} ≤ \frac{2}{k(k+1)}.$$
And it holds:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k(k+1)} = \sum_{k=1}^n[\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}] = 1 - \frac{1}{n+1}$$
Hence  $$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k(k+1)} → 1\qquad (n→∞),$$
und thus $\sum_{k=1}^∞\frac{1}{k^2}$ is convergent.

---

> Can a convergent sequence have no real limit ?

The answer is no. One of the ways real numbers can be described is by construction from Cauchy sequences. (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Construction_of_the_real_numbers#Construction_from_Cauchy_sequences))
The motivation for that construction is, that convergent sequences with elements in $ℚ$ not necessarily have their limit in $ℚ$.

By the construction $ℝ$ is the completion of $ℚ$. That means every Cauchy sequence (with elements in $ℝ$) converges in $ℝ$.

Comment: Thanks !! This helps a lot ... !

Answer (score 3):

The sequence $(u_n)_n$ defined by $$u_n=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac1i$$
**does not** converge. To see why, you can look up [harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics))

The sequence $(v_n)_n$ defined by $$v_n=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac1{i^2}$$
**does** converge.

They are **not** the same sequence, so there's no problem there.

---

The answer to your last question:

> Can a convergent sequence have no real limit ?

is **NO**. A sequence is convergent, **by definition**, if it has a limit.

Comment: Could you please explain why ... ?

Comment: @MSh Which one? Why the first diverges or why the second converges?

Comment: Sorry I'll fix the question to be clearer... no I know why the second converge

Comment: @MSh The first one is the harmonic series. It's well known it diverges (I added the link in the answer)

Comment: Thank you !! This is starting to make sense !!!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $u_n$ converges thus $u_n$ is a cauchy sequence, i.e:

$\forall \epsilon >0 ,\exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|u_n-u_m|< \frac{1}{2}, \forall m,n \geqslant n_0$

Let $m>n \geqslant n_0$

$|u_m-u_n|=|\frac{1}{n+1}+...+ \frac{1}{m}|$

For $m=2n$ we have that  $$\frac{1}{2}= \frac{n}{2n} \leqslant \frac{1}{2n}+...+\frac{1}{2n} \leqslant \frac{1}{n+1}+...+ \frac{1}{2n}< \frac{1}{2}$$ 
which is a contradiction.

$$Second-proof$$

We will prove that exists $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\log{(1 +\frac{1}{n})} \leqslant \frac{2}{n}$

This is easy because $n\log{(1 +\frac{1}{n})} \rightarrow \log{e}=1<2$

thus $\exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n \geqslant n_0$ we have that $$\frac{1}{n} \geqslant \frac{1}{2} \log{(1 +\frac{1}{n})}= \frac{1}{2}\log{(\frac{n+1}{n})}= \frac{1}{2}(\log{(n+1)}- \log{n})$$

Finally we have that $\forall n \geqslant n_0$ $$\sum_{i=1}^n \geqslant \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^n (\log{(i+1)}-\log{i})= \frac{1}{2} \log{(n+1)}$$

Take limits and you have your conclusion.

For the second part of your question use the fact that $\forall n \geqslant 2$
$$ \frac{1}{n^2} \leqslant \frac{1}{(n-1)n} =\frac{1}{n-1}- \frac{1}{n}$$

I hope this helps.

Comment: Appreciate the help... but I have no idea what you wrote means.. I'm just a normal High school student that's trying to make some sense of math ^-^

Comment: @Msh..I just proved the first part of you question with two ways..if you are not familiar with the definition of cauchy sequences then skip it and look the second proof.I assumed from your post that you know some things about summation and sequence limits.

Comment: In simpler way the sequence $u_n$ you mention in your post behaves like the sequence $a_n= \log{n}$ as $n$ approaches infinity where $a_n$ diverges to infinity as $n \rightarrow \infty$..(think that is like   $logx \rightarrow \infty$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$ ).

Comment: In more simpler words the sequence $u_n$ has no real end

Comment: Ah... Yeah my bad I just saw a few symbols I don't know what they mean in proof 1 and proof 2 is full with logarithm which I haven't learnt yet so I said that ... sorry now when I read it proof 1 does really make sense so lazy me says : Thank you !!