# How do you tell if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\ln(\frac{1}{n^2})$ converges or diverges and which test do you use?

Tags: sequences-and-series

For $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\ln(\frac{1}{n^2})$$ How do you tell if this series converges or diverges and which test do you use? I tried comparison test but it converges for me when it's supposed to diverge.

Comment: What did you compare with?

Comment: I compared it with ln(1/n)

Comment: When you have a series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ the first thing you do is to see whether $a_n\to 0$

Comment: Alright so in this case, it moves towards negative infinity. What if it did go to zero?

Comment: But $\ln(n^{-2})$ *doesn't* go to zero, so asking the hypothetical "what if it did" is pointless.  If you are asking about the general case, there are far too many techniques to say in a comment and it depends heavily on what the actual series is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the divergence test stating that a series is guaranteed to diverge if the series terms don’t go to zero in the limit.

If $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n\neq 0\Rightarrow \sum_n^\infty a_n$  diverges.

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}ln(\frac{1}{n^2})=-\infty\neq 0 \Rightarrow $ $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}ln(\frac{1}{n^2})$ diverges.

Comment: Thank you I got it now

Comment: No problem! If the series terms do happen to go to zero the series may or may not converge! This convergence test can only prove that a series diverges, not that it will converge. You should look up the harmonic series as an [example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/255/why-does-the-series-sum-n-1-infty-frac1n-not-converge)

Answer (score 3):

$$\ln \left( \frac{1}{n^2} \right) = - 2 \ln(n)$$

Therefore the general term of your series does not tend to $0$, so your series diverges.