# Converging or diverging

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

It is asked if it is convergent or Divergent series

```
1/(1*2) + 2/(3*4) + 3/(5*6)... infinity
```

Comment: What makes you say this has anything to do with a hyperbola?  Did you mean to say parabola instead?  If so, that is only the denominator and you neglected to take the numerator into account as well.

Comment: Really sorry, I posted wrong general term, this is the full que

Comment: Note that in this new version you display no effort whatsoever to solve the question.

Answer (score 1):

No; it diverges. First of all, note that $\dfrac n{n(n+1)}=\dfrac1{n+1}$. On the other hand, the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{n+1}$ is the harmonic series, which [diverges](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/255/why-does-the-series-sum-n-1-infty-frac1n-not-converge).

The series that you wrote after editing your question is $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac n{(2n-1)2n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{4n-2}$ which diverges too, since $(\forall n\in\mathbb N):\dfrac1{4n-2}\geqslant\dfrac14\times\dfrac1n$ and since the harmonic series diverges.

Comment: "the last term tends to zero and the graph is of hyperbola so it must be converging" is certainly NOT true!  (Actually there is no "last term".  I assume you mean the limit as n goes to 0.  Also the graph of n/n(n+1) is a sequence of individual points, not a hyperbola.  I assume you mean the graph of y= x/(x(x+ 1)), changing the discrete variable, n, to the continuous variable, x.)  The sum $\Sigma \frac{1}{n}$ has those properties but does not converge.

Comment: My guess is that you meant to comment the question, not my answer.

Comment: Really sorry, I posted wrong general term, this is the full question.