# Prove that the sequence defined by partial sums of the Harmonic series is not a Cauchy Sequence

Tags: real-analysis

*Prove that the sequence defined by partial sums of the Harmonic series*

$$\left\{S_n\right\}^{\infty}_{n=1} =\left\{\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k}\right\}^{\infty}_{n=1} $$
*is not a Cauchy sequence.*

I have a theorem that states

***Theorem***: A sequence is Cauchy if and only if it is convergent.

I first need help in understanding the proof that the Harmonic series is divergent. I somewhat understand that since its a sum and not a sequence that the sum will obviously go to infinity.I however get confused with the "sequence defined by partial sums of the Harmonic series" part.

second I was wondering that after proving that the sequence is indeed divergent that I can use the theorem to say its not cauchy. How would I go about wording that?

Comment: Hi, it is not true in general that a sequence must diverge to infinity. For example consider the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{n^2}$, or the simpler $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{2^n}$. You will find both converge.

Comment: The sequence of partial sums is $(H_n)$, where $H_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac1{n}$

Comment: For divergence of the series, have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/255/418131

Answer (score 3):

It might be more instructive not to use the theorem at all.

You can prove directly that $S_n=\sum^n_{k=1}\frac{1}{k}$ is not Cauchy: if $n>m,$ we have $S_n-S_m=\frac{1}{m+1} + \frac{1}{m+2}  +...+ \frac{1}{n} > \frac{n - m}{n} = 1 - m/n.$ Now, let $\epsilon=1/2.$ Then, if $n>2m,\ S_n-S_m> 1/2$ and so $(S_n)$ is not Cauchy.

Comment: I choose to approach another way, but your answer seems intriguing enough to learn. I don't quite understand the approach , however I will ask one of my professors to help me understand it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The wording is simple. Suppose, if possible, $(S_n)$ is Cauchy. Then, by the theorem, $S_n$ converges to some number $S$. By definition of convergence of  a series this means that the series $\sum \frac  1 n$ converges to $S$. But this series is not covergent. Hence, $(S_n)$ cannot be Cauchy.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence defined is $\{H_1,H_2,\cdots,H_n\}$ that is the sequence of the harmonic numbers and we know that it is divergent.

Yes, since tha theorem states an "*if and only if*" condition, we can conlude that the sequence is not Cauchy.

Answer (score 0):

Cauchy sequences are bounded, while $H_n$ is not:

$$ H_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k} > \sum_{k=1}^{n}\log\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\log(k+1)-\log(k) = \log(n).$$