# Quick number theory question on rational numbers

Tags: number-theory

Suppose all you had to work with was the set of numbers $\{n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ and $\{1/n\}$. Could you construct all other positive rational numbers from this set under addition using the finite number of elements in the basis of $\{1,2,3,...\}$ and $\{1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4}...\}$?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. If the number is m/n in lowest terms, multiply 1/n by m.

Comment: Maybe you should specify what you mean by "kind of basis." For example, the rational number $p/q$ is $1/q$ times the integer $p$; is this valid in your interpretation of "basis"?

Comment: What construction rules are you allowing, JRRs?

Comment: Through addition only, not multiplication.

Comment: Of course.  $r =\frac ab = \underbrace{\frac 1b + \frac 1b + ..... + \frac 1b}_{a\text{ times}}$.

Comment: "Through addition only, not multiplication"  Multiplication (by natural numbers) is addition a finite number of times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you allow repeated use of a number then you can construct a positive rational number $\frac{m}{n}$ as the sum

$$\underbrace{ \frac{1}{n} + \dots + \frac{1}{n} }_{m \text{ times}}.$$

So the interesting question is what happens if you are only allowed to use the available numbers at most once each. In that case it is still possible, and in fact you don't need the positive integers, you can use just the unit fractions $\{ \frac{1}{n} \}$. This is the classical result about the existence of [Egyptian fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_fraction) representations. A simple way to prove that these exist is to start from the above sum and repeatedly apply the identity

$$\frac{1}{k} = \frac{1}{k+1} + \frac{1}{k(k+1)}$$

until all the unit fractions that appear are distinct, although this gives many terms with very large denominators and I think a greedy method (subtracting the largest possible unit fraction at each step) usually does better.

(Sketch of a proof that this works: initially there are $m$ identical unit fractions in the sum. After applying the above identity to $m-1$ of them, there are $2$ sets of $m-1$ identical fractions in the sum. After applying the identity to $m-2$ of each of these two sets there are $4 = 2^2$ sets of $m-2$ identical fractions... at some point in this process there may be "accidental" collisions but you can just keep going until those disappear too.)

Comment: And therefore, [the harmonic series diverges](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3880131/30836).

Comment: @Micah: yes, that's a nice corollary!