# Proof of Divergence of infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

This is a part of a question to show absolute convergence/divergence of improper integrals.

So my professor simplified the question to this $\frac{2}{\pi} \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n+1} $ and then proceeded to say that "it is a well known fact that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n+1} $ diverges".

My question is that shouldn't it converge ? As I can say that the values of the individual terms in the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n+1} $ will finally tend to $0$ as $n$ approaches $\infty$.

I cannot ask this in class as the lectures are pre recorded and the doubt session is quite far away.

Comment: Look up the harmonic series.

Comment: Specifically, see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/255/215011

Comment: $a_n\to 0$ doesn't imply that the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges. Actually, $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}$ is the most standard example of a divergent series.

Comment: You may have heard somewhere that *if* $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges *then* $a_n\to 0$.  This is a one way implication... $P\implies Q$.  This is not a bi-implication.  The converse is not logically equivalent and is outright false in this case, the harmonic series being a stereotypical counterexample.